# Add a universal property to the MatDialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

I want to add the property `disableClose` with the value `true` to all MatDialogs in my Angular app.

I've searched already and tried to set the property `disableClose` in the `app.module.ts` file. But that didn't work.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a custom component that is a clone of `MatDialog`, but uses `MatDialog` with the property `disableClose` as default.

Comment: Thank you. :) I decided to use an own Popup-Service therefore. In this service I can set this property for all popups.

Comment: feel free to mark it as solved then...